# How can I make an RF source with various frequencies?

Tags: arduino, rf, electromagnetic

I have been working on a new electromagnetic shielding material. A part of the project is testing it and finding its electromagnetic shielding effectiveness (SE).

For instance, I could use a transmitter and a receiver. Then, I would measure the intensity of the electromagnetic waves before and after applying the electromagnetic shield. However, this requires some equipment that I don't have access to. I was wondering whether I could make an RF source with various frequencies and measure the SE using arduino UNO or any other way. I could also measure SE using power density, electric field intensity, and magnetic field intensity before and after applying the shield. However, I don't know what equipment I can use that are available for a limited project.

You could read more about electromagnetic shielding and how to measure it in the first section of this paper:
https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10853-020-05635-x.pdf

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a job for a software defined radio with transmit capabilities. You’ll need a lot more than just an arduino uno to accomplish a similar task.

Comment: Could you tell me what you have in mind?

Comment: Try researching [SDR](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=software+defined+radio&t=opera&ia=web)

Comment: Unless you know what you're doing and the pitfalls of making such a measurement, you might consider contracting this out.

Comment: Is your material reflective or absorptive to RF?

Comment: @The Photon It is mainly reflective

Comment: You really need a network analyzer, which will give you information on the power that's reflected, as well as the power that's received. If you ignore the power that's reflected, then your through power will look artificially low. You also need to think about how you're going to couple the power into the shielding material.